# setTextColor error

Tags: java, text

I just began using eclipse and have no experience with java but I am following a tutorial and got stuck with this text color problem.  The error that I am getting says RED cannot be resolved or is not a field.  Here's the code, all help is appreciated.

```
case R.id.myRadioButtonRed: myMessage.setTextColor(Color.RED); break;
```

Comment: You might want to add a tag for the language you are writing in.

Comment: You forgot to import something http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Answer (score 1):

Going by the R.id.myRadioButtonRed it looks like this is an Android project. In the Android SDK java.awt.Color does not exist. You need to use [android.graphics.Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html)

Comment: case R.id.myRadioButtonRed: myMessage.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED); break;

That should work. I don't have the Android SDK installed at the moment to test it. It would also be helpful to know what type myMessage is. I'm assuming setTextColor takes an int that represents a color.

Comment: yes that seems to work. thank you.  But I have another question. How do I declare a constant for myRadioButtonRed?  I click on it and click declare as constant but when I try to run it, it doesn't work. It says R.java was modified manually.  Do I have to declare myRadioButtonRed somewhere else?  This is the code that i get in R.java:  protected static final int myRadioButtonRed = 0;

Comment: That's a bit out of the scope of this question and I'd recommend posting another question for it. Also, please accept my answer (click the little checkbox near it) if it worked for you. Thanks!